# Geocoding services using Angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

My requirement is- write a program in angular js to enter a city name in a textbox, have 2 buttons for printing its temps in degree celcius, fahrenheit. also print its latitude and longitude. Upon refresh the values should hold and only changes on entering a new city. I have the below code. I am able to get the temperatures but not the latitude, longitude and refresh thing. cannot use jquery.

```
index.html-

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>First AngularJS Application</title>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="weatherService.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body ng-app='WeatherApp' >
    <div ng-controller="main as vm">
        <h1> City details</h1>
        <p class="error">
            {{vm.error}}
          </p>

    <form name="weatherForm"></form>
    Enter city: 
    <input type="search" ng-model="vm.query" placeholder="Enter City Name Here" name="city" class="form-control"   required/> <br>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Centigrade" ng-click="vm.SearchC()" />
  <input type="submit" value="Fahrenheit" ng-click="vm.SearchF()" /> <br> <br>
    </form>
    <div ng-include="'index.html'" ng-show="vm.ValidDataLoaded"></div>
  City: <span>{{vm.query}}</span>  <br>
  
<span >Latitude: {{address.components.location.lat}}</span><br>
<span >Longitude: {{address.components.location.long}}</span><br>
<!--
  *<span>{{vm.Temperatures}}</span><br>
  *<span>{{vm.Temperatures1}}</span><br>
  -->
  Degree Centigrade: <span ng-repeat="temp in vm.Temperatures | orderBy:'Units'">{{temp.Currentc}}</span> <br>
  Degree Fahrenheit: <span ng-repeat="temp in vm.Temperatures1 | orderBy:'Units'">{{temp.Currentf}}</span> 
</body>
</html>

script.js-
(function() {

    angular
      .module('WeatherApp', [])
      .controller('main', ['weatherService',
        function (weatherService) {
  
          var vm = this;
          vm.SearchC = function() {
  
            weatherService.GetWeather(vm.query)
              .then(function(data) {
  
                // Copy data from the service into the model
                vm.City = data.City;
                vm.Temperatures = data.Temperatures;
                  
                // If we got this far, we have good data
                vm.ValidDataLoaded = true;
  
              })
  
            .catch (function(message) {
    
                vm.error = message;
                vm.ValidDataLoaded = false;
    
              });
  
          }; // End Search()

          vm.SearchF = function() {
  
            weatherService.GetWeather(vm.query)
              .then(function(data) {
  
                // Copy data from the service into the model
                vm.City = data.City;
                vm.Temperatures1 = data.Temperatures;
                  
                // If we got this far, we have good data
                vm.ValidDataLoaded = true;
  
              })
  
            .catch (function(message) {
    
                vm.error = message;
                vm.ValidDataLoaded = false;
    
              });
  
          }; // End Search()
        }
      ]); // End Controller()
  }()); // End IFFE


  weatherService.js-
(function() {

    var module = angular
      .module('WeatherApp')
      
      .constant('appId', '842496b0937af89d638ce9a89b0a142e')
      .factory("weatherService", ['$http', '$log', '$q', 'appId',
      
       function weatherService($http, $log, $q, appId) {
  
          var getWeather = function getWeather(location) {
  
            $log.info("Retrieving weather for " + location);
  
            return $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + location +
            '&appid=' + appId)
            
              .then(function sendResponseData(response) {
  
                // Success
                $log.info("Retrieved weather for " + location);
  
                var data = response.data;
                return {
                  
                  // Return the weather data in nicer format than the web service
                  City: data.name,
                  Temperatures: GetTemperatures(data.main),
                  Temperatures1: GetTemperatures(data.main)
                  
                }
  
              }).catch(function(response) {
  
                $log.error('HTTP request error: ' + response.status)
                return $q.reject('Error: ' + response.status);
  
              });
          }; // End getWeather()
  
          // In weatherService()
          return {
            GetWeather: getWeather
          };
          
        } // End weatherService()
      ]);
  
    // Private functions ------------------------------------------------
  
    //
    // GetTemperatures() - Extracts temperatures from weather data
    //
    var GetTemperatures = function GetTemperatures(temps) {
      return [{
        "Units": "Farenheit",
        "Currentf": GetFarenheit(temps.temp)
        
      }, {
        "Units": "Celsius",
        "Currentc": GetCelsius(temps.temp)
        
      }, {
        "Units": "Kelvin",
        "Current": GetKelvin(temps.temp)
       
      }];
    }; // End GetTemperatures()
  
    //
    // GetFarenheit() - Convert a temperature in weather data to F
    //
    var GetFarenheit = function GetFarenheit(temp) {
      return ((temp - 273) * (9 / 5)) + 32;
    }; // End GetFarenheit()
  
    //
    // GetKelvin() - Convert a temperature in weather data to K
    //
    var GetKelvin = function GetKelvin(temp) {
      return temp;
    }; // End GetKelvin()
  
    //
    // GetCelsius() - Convert a temperature in weather data to C
    //
    var GetCelsius = function GetCelsius(temp) {
      return temp - 273;
    }; // End GetCelsius
  
  
  }());
```